# Is it possible to solve $6\cos x+2\sqrt{2}\sin x=\sqrt{22}$ without using arc functions?

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve for x which is in $[0;2\pi]$.
> $$6\cos x+2\sqrt{2}\sin x=\sqrt{22}$$

I have solved the question by dividing both sides $\sqrt{44}$, and got the answer that involves arcsin function. My question is:

> Is it possible to solve it without any arc functions?

Comment: Could you explain why you aren't happy with the solution you got?

Comment: No it is not that I am unhappy. I just thought it would be better if there was no arc function lingering. If it is not possible, that's ok though.

Comment: Given the coefficients in this equation, you aren't going to end up with solutions that are multiples or subdivisions of $ \ \pi/6 \ $ or $ \ \pi/4 \ $ .  The equation $ \ A \cos x \ + \ B \sin x \ = \ C \ $ isn't generally going to have "nice" solutions (when they exist); only specifically-constructed textbook problems have those sorts of answers.

Comment: @ Uailibek Nurgulan Short answer is..  Analytical solution no...Numerical solution  yes..

Answer (score 3):

$$6\cos x=\sqrt{22}-2\sqrt2\sin x$$

and by squaring,

$$36(1-\sin^2x)=8\sin^2x-8\sqrt{11}\sin x+22.$$

We solve the quadratic equation in $\sin x$ and get the two solutions

$$\sin x=\frac{4\sqrt{11}\pm24\sqrt2}{326},\\\cos x=\frac{\sqrt{22}-2\sqrt2\sin x}6.$$

---

Anyway, you can't solve for $x$ without some inverse trigonometric function. The above resolution yields algebraic numbers, but the solution in $x$ is not, and you can't avoid a transcendental function.

Comment: I guess we need $\arcsin$ to find $x$..$\ddot \smile$

Comment: @lonestudent: we don't to find $\sin x,\cos x$.

Comment: It is interesting. But, OP wrote "Solve for $x$"

Comment: @lonestudent: good point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Write the equation as follows:

$$\begin{align}(3 + i \sqrt 2) e^{-ix} + (3 - i\sqrt 2) e^{ix} &= \sqrt{22}&\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}x &= 2 π n - i \log\left(±\frac{(1 ± i) \sqrt {\frac{11}{2}}}{\sqrt 2 + 3 i}\right),& n \in\mathbb Z&\end{align}$$

Also, you can use this well-known formula:

$$\begin{align}\arctan x&=\frac 12 i \log(1 - i x) - \frac 12 i \log(1 + i x)&\end{align}$$

Comment: Taking the logarithm of a complex involves an arc tangent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust in general formula for $a\sin x+b\cos x =c$ we need $\arctan $ So, I replaced $\arctan x$ with complex logarithm. Do you think it is not valid?

Comment: IMO, a complex logarithm is *worse* than an arc tangent (especially if one implements that formula straight away using complex numbers).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. Then, Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No, I even upvoted it, for originality of the approach.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you .!!(off topic)can I ask a question?  I see the word IMO in a lot of comments in MS.E. But I don't know who to ask about the meaning of the word.  What does this word mean?  Is it a word like WLOG? Google translate cannot translate. The only thing i know (IMO=International mathematical olympiad)

Comment: In my opinion, it means something else ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have *approximations* of the solution.

Consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=6\cos (x)+2\sqrt{2}\sin (x)-\sqrt{22}$$ SInce we know at least the exact trigonometric values of multiples of $\frac \pi{24}$, in the considered range, it is easy to show that
$$\frac {9\pi}{24} < x_1 <\frac {5\pi}{12} \qquad \text{and} \qquad\frac {45\pi}{24} < x_2 <\frac {23\pi}{12} $$ If you do not want to use a purely numerical method such as Newton which would work like a charm; consider the infinite series representation
$$f(x)=6\cos (a)+2\sqrt{2}\sin (a)-\sqrt{22}+$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ \Big[6 \cos \left(a+n\frac{\pi  }{2}\right)+ 2 \sqrt{2} \sin \left(a+n\frac{\pi  }{2}\right)\Big]}{n!}\,(x-a)^n$$ Truncate the expansion to any order and use series reversion.

For example, use the terms up to $(x-a)^6$.

For $a=\frac {9\pi}{24}$ you will obtain an explicit  reult (too long to be written here) and its numerical evaluation gives
$$x_1=1.2259088208$$ while the exact solution is
$x_1=1.2259088264$

For $a=\frac {45\pi}{24}$, you will obtain $$x_2=5.9382978047$$ while the exact solution is $x_2=5.9382978068$.

*Are you sure that you want to face such a nigtmare ?*